# How to count the alphabet letters occur in a given text (string) in assembly language?

Tags: assembly

I'm building a program that is going to count how many time each letter of the alphabet occurs in a given text. For example, if the text is "Hello World" then the output will be like:

H - 1 time
e - 1 time
l - 3 times
o - 2 times
W - 1 time
r - 1 time
d - 1 time

The problem is we have to differentiate the upper and lower case. 
I got a snippet code from google, but I don't really understand part of the code. I put a comment of the code that I know what it does. Can someone please explain it to me ? thank you.

```
buffer  BYTE "AAbcd", 0
charInput   BYTE 26 DUP(0)    ; should the array size be greater than 26 ?
                              ; since we will need to counter the upper and lower ones



    CharCount PROC
    pushad

    XOR ebx, ebx
    XOR eax, eax
    XOR edx, edx
    mov esi, 0
    mov edi, 0
L1:
    mov al, buffer[esi]
    sub eax, 65 
    mov dl, charInput[edi + eax]    ; it stores the values at position [edi + eax] into dx ???
    inc dl                  ; 

    mov charInput[edi + eax], dl    ; what does it do in here ???
    inc esi             
    loop L1

    popad
    ret
CharCount ENDP


END main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give it a shot. I, too, am rusty on assembly. Let me just comment it up a bit more.

```
buffer  BYTE "AAbcd", 0
charInput   BYTE 26 DUP(0)    ; should the array size be greater than 26 ? Yes - you may want to do 0-255 here
                          ; since we will need to counter the upper and lower ones



CharCount PROC
pushad                    ; push registers as backup

XOR ebx, ebx              ; shortcut to store 0 in ebx
XOR eax, eax              ; same for eax - your letter code will be here (A=0, Z=25)
XOR edx, edx              ; zero out edx. edx is your current register for storing the frequency
mov esi, 0                ; zero out esi - esi is the index to the letter being processed from the string
mov edi, 0                ; zero out edi as well - it doesn't seem like edi is ever non-zero here
L1:
mov al, buffer[esi]       ; grab the current letter to process and put into al (low part of eax)
sub eax, 65               ; substract 65 to shift ASCII A down to 0. You may wish to not shift this value and instead just use a larger array of 0-255.
mov dl, charInput[edi + eax]    ; grab the current frequency of the letter from charInput, the "histogram"
inc dl                  ; increment the frequency by one

mov charInput[edi + eax], dl    ; put it back into the histogram
inc esi                   ; move on to the next letter to proces
loop L1                   ; go back to the next letter

popad                     ; pop registers
ret
CharCount ENDP


END main
```

After this you'll need to iterate over your expanded charInput and dump out the number of occurrences. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for an explanation rather than debugged code, so that's what I shall provide.

In the comments you ask

> ; should the array size be greater than 26 ?

If by "differentiate upper-case and lower-case" you mean you want to count the number of `a` separately from the number of `A`, then you'll need your array to hold 52 entries, and will also need to range-check the input characters.  The number 65 is an ASCII upper-case `A`, lower-case `a` in ASCII is 97 (32 more), though using character constants in the code will help considerably in making it more readable.

That's the easy one.

The line where you ask

> ; what does it do in here ???

is indexing into the array where you're doing the counting: having got the number and incremented it it's then putting the value back.  As @J-trana says, `edi` doesn't look like it's ever used: my guess is that it was intended to make the upper-case/lower-case distinction easier and would hold the value 32 if the character is lower-case (by ANDing `buffer[esi]` with 32).  A result of that would be that the array should not be 52 but 64 bytes long.

Again, J-trana has correctly suggested making the array big enough to hold every possible value, so 256 bytes.  That would simplify the indexing and almost certainly remove the need to use `edi` at all.

That's the one you asked.

There is of course the "gotcha" in there, which is that your `LOOP` relies on `cx` but nothing has set it. The easy way to do that is to calculate it as charInput - buffer just before L1.